# Heroku app is suddenly giving a 503 via my API call

Tags: ruby-on-rails, api, heroku, restkit

I have my API setup for my mobile app. I haven't changed anything on my ROR server running on Heroku and in my App I haven't changed the API call. I am using RestKit which which updated, but literally all but this ONE api call is working just as before.

I am running Charles ands sniffed what is being sent and received.

REQUEST:

```
http://app-staging.herokuapp.com/v1/cars/request.json
Complete
503 Service Unavailable
HTTP/1.1
-
POST
No
text/html; charset=utf-8
/127.0.0.1
app-staging.herokuapp.com/52.405.77.212
```

TEXT:

```
api_key=ABC&auth_token=bWgk_hSt1&dropoff_address=&dropoff_lat=&dropoff_lng=&max_distance=10&pickup_address=2300%20Len%20St%2C%20Boston%20NE&pickup_lat=20.28734332335819&pickup_lng=-77.74977593451985&round_trip=FALSE&type=Delivery
```

RESPONSE:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
      <head>
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <title>Application Error</title>
        <style media="screen">
          html,body,iframe {
            margin: 0;
            padding: 0;
          }
          html,body {
            height: 100%;
            overflow: hidden;
          }
          iframe {
            width: 100%;
            height: 100%;
            border: 0;
          }
        </style>
      </head>
      <body>
        <iframe src="//www.herokucdn.com/error-pages/application-error.html"></iframe>
      </body>
    </html>
```

LOGS:

```
Started POST "/v1/cars/request.json" for 70.224.555.346 at 2020-03-31 20:50:35 +0000
Mar 31 15:50:35 app-staging app/web.1: [AWS SimpleDB 200 0.1589 0 retries] select(:consistent_read=>false,:select_expression=>"SELECT * FROM `b-staging_Geocode` WHERE `hash` = 'd41d8cd427e' LIMIT 1")  
Mar 31 15:50:35 app-staging app/web.1: 
Mar 31 15:51:05 app-staging heroku/router: at=error code=H12 desc="Request timeout" method=POST path="/v1/cars/request.json" host=app-staging.herokuapp.com request_id=6227d87c-467f-445c-bd28-2e54932792f6 fwd="70.324.555.246" dyno=web.1 connect=1ms service=30051ms status=503 bytes=0 protocol=http
Mar 31 15:51:38 app-staging app/web.1: /app/vendor/ruby-2.4.2/lib/ruby/2.4.0/net/http.rb:904:in `initialize'
Mar 31 15:51:38 app-staging app/web.1: /app/vendor/ruby-2.4.2/lib/ruby/2.4.0/net/http.rb:904:in `open'
Mar 31 15:51:38 app-staging app/web.1: /app/vendor/ruby-2.4.2/lib/ruby/2.4.0/net/http.rb:904:in `block in connect'
Mar 31 15:51:38 app-staging app/web.1: /app/vendor/ruby-2.4.2/lib/ruby/2.4.0/timeout.rb:103:in `timeout'
Mar 31 15:51:38 app-staging app/web.1: /app/vendor/ruby-2.4.2/lib/ruby/2.4.0/net/http.rb:902:in `connect'
Mar 31 15:51:38 app-staging app/web.1: /app/vendor/ruby-2.4.2/lib/ruby/2.4.0/net/http.rb:887:in `do_start'
Mar 31 15:51:38 app-staging app/web.1: /app/vendor/ruby-2.4.2/lib/ruby/2.4.0/net/http.rb:876:in `start'
Mar 31 15:51:38 app-staging app/web.1: /app/vendor/ruby-2.4.2/lib/ruby/2.4.0/net/http.rb:1407:in `request'
Mar 31 15:51:38 app-staging app/web.1: /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.4.0/gems/newrelic_rpm-6.3.0.355/lib/new_relic/agent/instrumentation/net.rb:36:in `block in request_with_newrelic_trace'
Mar 31 15:51:38 app-staging app/web.1: /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.4.0/gems/newrelic_rpm-6.3.0.355/lib/new_relic/agent.rb:505:in `disable_all_tracing'
Mar 31 15:51:38 app-staging app/web.1: /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.4.0/gems/newrelic_rpm-6.3.0.355/lib/new_relic/agent/instrumentation/net.rb:35:in `request_with_newrelic_trace'
Mar 31 15:51:38 app-staging app/web.1: /app/config/initializers/constants.rb:339:in `kue_job'
Mar 31 15:51:38 app-staging app/web.1: /app/app/models/car_request.rb:516:in `request_car'
Mar 31 15:51:38 app-staging app/web.1: /app/lib/api_v1/cars.rb:199:in `block (2 levels) in <class:cars>'
Mar 31 15:51:38 app-staging app/web.1: /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.4.0/gems/grape-0.13.0/lib/grape/endpoint.rb:51:in `call'
Mar 31 15:51:38 app-staging app/web.1: /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.4.0/gems/grape-0.13.0/lib/grape/endpoint.rb:51:in `block (2 levels) in generate_api_method'
Mar 31 15:51:38 app-staging app/web.1: /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.4.0/gems/activesupport-4.2.11.1/lib/active_support/notifications.rb:166:in `instrument'
Mar 31 15:51:38 app-staging app/web.1: /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.4.0/gems/grape-0.13.0/lib/grape/endpoint.rb:50:in `block in generate_api_method'
Mar 31 15:51:38 app-staging app/web.1: /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.4.0/gems/grape-0.13.0/lib/grape/endpoint.rb:254:in `block in run'
Mar 31 15:51:38 app-staging app/web.1: /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.4.0/gems/activesupport-4.2.11.1/lib/active_support/notifications.rb:166:in `instrument'
Mar 31 15:51:38 app-staging app/web.1: /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.4.0/gems/grape-0.13.0/lib/grape/endpoint.rb:219:in `run'
Mar 31 15:51:38 app-staging app/web.1: /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.4.0/gems/grape-0.13.0/lib/grape/endpoint.rb:201:in `block in call!'
Mar 31 15:51:38 app-staging app/web.1: /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.4.0/gems/newrelic-grape-2.1.0/lib/newrelic-grape/instrument.rb:21:in `block in call!'
Mar 31 15:51:38 app-staging app/web.1: /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.4.0/gems/newrelic_rpm-6.3.0.355/lib/new_relic/agent/instrumentation/controller_instrumentation.rb:376:in `perform_action_with_newrelic_trace'
Mar 31 15:51:38 app-staging app/web.1: /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.4.0/gems/newrelic-grape-2.1.0/lib/newrelic-grape/instrument.rb:20:in `call!'
Mar 31 15:51:38 app-staging app/web.1: /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.4.0/gems/grape-0.13.0/lib/grape/middleware/base.rb:18:in `call'
Mar 31 15:51:38 app-staging app/web.1: /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.4.0/gems/newrelic_rpm-6.3.0.355/lib/new_relic/agent/instrumentation/middleware_tracing.rb:99:in `call'
Mar 31 15:51:38 app-staging app/web.1: /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.4.0/gems/grape-0.13.0/lib/grape/middleware/base.rb:24:in `call!'
Mar 31 15:51:38 app-staging app/web.1: /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.4.0/gems/grape-0.13.0/lib/grape/middleware/base.rb:18:in `call'
Mar 31 15:51:38 app-staging app/web.1: /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.4.0/gems/newrelic_rpm-6.3.0.355/lib/new_relic/agent/instrumentation/middleware_tracing.rb:99:in `call'
Mar 31 15:51:38 app-staging app/web.1: /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.4.0/gems/grape-0.13.0/lib/grape/middleware/base.rb:24:in `call!'
Mar 31 15:51:38 app-staging app/web.1: /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.4.0/gems/grape-0.13.0/lib/grape/middleware/base.rb:18:in `call'
Mar 31 15:51:38 app-staging app/web.1: /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.4.0/gems/newrelic_rpm-6.3.0.355/lib/new_relic/agent/instrumentation/middleware_tracing.rb:99:in `call'
Mar 31 15:51:38 app-staging app/web.1: /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.4.0/gems/grape-0.13.0/lib/grape/middleware/error.rb:27:in `block in call!'
Mar 31 15:51:38 app-staging app/web.1: /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.4.0/gems/grape-0.13.0/lib/grape/middleware/error.rb:26:in `catch'
Mar 31 15:51:38 app-staging app/web.1: /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.4.0/gems/grape-0.13.0/lib/grape/middleware/error.rb:26:in `call!'
Mar 31 15:51:38 app-staging app/web.1: /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.4.0/gems/grape-0.13.0/lib/grape/middleware/base.rb:18:in `call'
Mar 31 15:51:38 app-staging app/web.1: /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.4.0/gems/newrelic_rpm-6.3.0.355/lib/new_relic/agent/instrumentation/middleware_tracing.rb:99:in `call'
Mar 31 15:51:38 app-staging app/web.1: /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.4.0/gems/rack-1.6.11/lib/rack/head.rb:13:in `call'
Mar 31 15:51:38 app-staging app/web.1: /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.4.0/gems/newrelic_rpm-6.3.0.355/lib/new_relic/agent/instrumentation/middleware_tracing.rb:99:in `call'
Mar 31 15:51:38 app-staging app/web.1: /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.4.0/gems/rack-1.6.11/lib/rack/builder.rb:153:in `call'
Mar 31 15:51:38 app-staging app/web.1: /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.4.0/gems/grape-0.13.0/lib/grape/endpoint.rb:202:in `call!'
Mar 31 15:51:38 app-staging app/web.1: /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.4.0/gems/grape-0.13.0/lib/grape/endpoint.rb:190:in `call'
Mar 31 15:51:38 app-staging app/web.1: /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.4.0/gems/rack-mount-0.8.3/lib/rack/mount/route_set.rb:152:in `block in call'
Mar 31 15:51:38 app-staging app/web.1: /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.4.0/gems/rack-mount-0.8.3/lib/rack/mount/code_generation.rb:96:in `block in recognize'
Mar 31 15:51:38 app-staging app/web.1: /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.4.0/gems/rack-mount-0.8.3/lib/rack/mount/code_generation.rb:75:in `optimized_each'
Mar 31 15:51:38 app-staging app/web.1: /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.4.0/gems/rack-mount-0.8.3/lib/rack/mount/code_generation.rb:95:in `recognize'
Mar 31 15:51:38 app-staging app/web.1: /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.4.0/gems/rack-mount-0.8.3/lib/rack/mount/route_set.rb:141:in `call'
Mar 31 15:51:38 app-staging app/web.1: /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.4.0/gems/grape-0.13.0/lib/grape/api.rb:114:in `call'
Mar 31 15:51:38 app-staging app/web.1: /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.4.0/gems/grape-0.13.0/lib/grape/api.rb:44:in `call!'
Mar 31 15:51:38 app-staging app/web.1: /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.4.0/gems/grape-0.13.0/lib/grape/api.rb:39:in `call'
Mar 31 15:51:38 app-staging app/web.1: /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.4.0/gems/actionpack-4.2.11.1/lib/action_dispatch/routing/mapper.rb:51:in `serve'
Mar 31 15:51:38 app-staging app/web.1: /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.4.0/gems/actionpack-4.2.11.1/lib/action_dispatch/journey/router.rb:43:in `block in serve'
Mar 31 15:51:38 app-staging app/web.1: /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.4.0/gems/actionpack-4.2.11.1/lib/action_dispatch/journey/router.rb:30:in `each'
Mar 31 15:51:38 app-staging app/web.1: /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.4.0/gems/actionpack-4.2.11.1/lib/action_dispatch/journey/router.rb:30:in `serve'
Mar 31 15:51:38 app-staging app/web.1: /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.4.0/gems/actionpack-4.2.11.1/lib/action_dispatch/routing/route_set.rb:817:in `call'
Mar 31 15:51:38 app-staging app/web.1: /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.4.0/gems/newrelic_rpm-6.3.0.355/lib/new_relic/agent/instrumentation/middleware_tracing.rb:99:in `call'
Mar 31 15:51:38 app-staging app/web.1: /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.4.0/gems/newrelic_rpm-6.3.0.355/lib/new_relic/rack/agent_hooks.rb:30:in `traced_call'
Mar 31 15:51:38 app-staging app/web.1: /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.4.0/gems/newrelic_rpm-6.3.0.355/lib/new_relic/agent/instrumentation/middleware_tracing.rb:99:in `call'
Mar 31 15:51:38 app-staging app/web.1: /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.4.0/gems/newrelic_rpm-6.3.0.355/lib/new_relic/rack/browser_monitoring.rb:32:in `traced_call'
Mar 31 15:51:38 app-staging app/web.1: /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.4.0/gems/newrelic_rpm-6.3.0.355/lib/new_relic/agent/instrumentation/middleware_tracing.rb:99:in `call'
Mar 31 15:51:38 app-staging app/web.1: /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.4.0/gems/warden-1.2.7/lib/warden/manager.rb:36:in `block in call'
Mar 31 15:51:38 app-staging app/web.1: /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.4.0/gems/warden-1.2.7/lib/warden/manager.rb:35:in `catch'
Mar 31 15:51:38 app-staging app/web.1: /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.4.0/gems/warden-1.2.7/lib/warden/manager.rb:35:in `call'
Mar 31 15:51:38 app-staging app/web.1: /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.4.0/gems/newrelic_rpm-6.3.0.355/lib/new_relic/agent/instrumentation/middleware_tracing.rb:99:in `call'
Mar 31 15:51:38 app-staging app/web.1: /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.4.0/gems/rack-1.6.11/lib/rack/etag.rb:24:in `call'
Mar 31 15:51:38 app-staging app/web.1: /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.4.0/gems/newrelic_rpm-6.3.0.355/lib/new_relic/agent/instrumentation/middleware_tracing.rb:99:in `call'
Mar 31 15:51:38 app-staging app/web.1: /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.4.0/gems/rack-1.6.11/lib/rack/conditionalget.rb:38:in `call'
Mar 31 15:51:38 app-staging app/web.1: /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.4.0/gems/newrelic_rpm-6.3.0.355/lib/new_relic/agent/instrumentation/middleware_tracing.rb:99:in `call'
Mar 31 15:51:38 app-staging app/web.1: /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.4.0/gems/rack-1.6.11/lib/rack/head.rb:13:in `call'
Mar 31 15:51:38 app-staging app/web.1: /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.4.0/gems/newrelic_rpm-6.3.0.355/lib/new_relic/agent/instrumentation/middleware_tracing.rb:99:in `call'
Mar 31 15:51:38 app-staging app/web.1: /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.4.0/gems/actionpack-4.2.11.1/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/params_parser.rb:27:in `call'
Mar 31 15:51:38 app-staging app/web.1: /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.4.0/gems/newrelic_rpm-6.3.0.355/lib/new_relic/agent/instrumentation/middleware_tracing.rb:99:in `call'
Mar 31 15:51:38 app-staging app/web.1: /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.4.0/gems/actionpack-4.2.11.1/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/flash.rb:260:in `call'
Mar 31 15:51:38 app-staging app/web.1: /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.4.0/gems/newrelic_rpm-6.3.0.355/lib/new_relic/agent/instrumentation/middleware_tracing.rb:99:in `call'
Mar 31 15:51:38 app-staging app/web.1: /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.4.0/gems/rack-1.6.11/lib/rack/session/abstract/id.rb:225:in `context'
Mar 31 15:51:38 app-staging app/web.1: /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.4.0/gems/rack-1.6.11/lib/rack/session/abstract/id.rb:220:in `call'
Mar 31 15:51:38 app-staging app/web.1: /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.4.0/gems/newrelic_rpm-6.3.0.355/lib/new_relic/agent/instrumentation/middleware_tracing.rb:99:in `call'
Mar 31 15:51:38 app-staging app/web.1: /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.4.0/gems/actionpack-4.2.11.1/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/cookies.rb:560:in `call'
Mar 31 15:51:38 app-staging app/web.1: /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.4.0/gems/newrelic_rpm-6.3.0.355/lib/new_relic/agent/instrumentation/middleware_tracing.rb:99:in `call'
Mar 31 15:51:38 app-staging app/web.1: /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.4.0/gems/actionpack-4.2.11.1/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/callbacks.rb:29:in `block in call'
Mar 31 15:51:38 app-staging app/web.1: /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.4.0/gems/activesupport-4.2.11.1/lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:88:in `__run_callbacks__'
Mar 31 15:51:38 app-staging app/web.1: /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.4.0/gems/activesupport-4.2.11.1/lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:778:in `_run_call_callbacks'
Mar 31 15:51:38 app-staging app/web.1: /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.4.0/gems/activesupport-4.2.11.1/lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:81:in `run_callbacks'
Mar 31 15:51:38 app-staging app/web.1: /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.4.0/gems/actionpack-4.2.11.1/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/callbacks.rb:27:in `call'
Mar 31 15:51:38 app-staging app/web.1: /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.4.0/gems/newrelic_rpm-6.3.0.355/lib/new_relic/agent/instrumentation/middleware_tracing.rb:99:in `call'
Mar 31 15:51:38 app-staging app/web.1: /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.4.0/gems/actionpack-4.2.11.1/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/remote_ip.rb:78:in `call'
Mar 31 15:51:38 app-staging app/web.1: /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.4.0/gems/newrelic_rpm-6.3.0.355/lib/new_relic/agent/instrumentation/middleware_tracing.rb:99:in `call'
Mar 31 15:51:38 app-staging app/web.1: /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.4.0/gems/actionpack-4.2.11.1/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/debug_exceptions.rb:17:in `call'
Mar 31 15:51:38 app-staging app/web.1: /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.4.0/gems/newrelic_rpm-6.3.0.355/lib/new_relic/agent/instrumentation/middleware_tracing.rb:99:in `call'
Mar 31 15:51:38 app-staging app/web.1: /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.4.0/gems/actionpack-4.2.11.1/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/show_exceptions.rb:30:in `call'
Mar 31 15:51:38 app-staging app/web.1: /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.4.0/gems/newrelic_rpm-6.3.0.355/lib/new_relic/agent/instrumentation/middleware_tracing.rb:99:in `call'
Mar 31 15:51:38 app-staging app/web.1: /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.4.0/gems/railties-4.2.11.1/lib/rails/rack/logger.rb:38:in `call_app'
Mar 31 15:51:38 app-staging app/web.1: /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.4.0/gems/railties-4.2.11.1/lib/rails/rack/logger.rb:20:in `block in call'
Mar 31 15:51:38 app-staging app/web.1: /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.4.0/gems/activesupport-4.2.11.1/lib/active_support/tagged_logging.rb:68:in `block in tagged'
Mar 31 15:51:38 app-staging app/web.1: /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.4.0/gems/activesupport-4.2.11.1/lib/active_support/tagged_logging.rb:26:in `tagged'
Mar 31 15:51:38 app-staging app/web.1: /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.4.0/gems/activesupport-4.2.11.1/lib/active_support/tagged_logging.rb:68:in `tagged'
Mar 31 15:51:38 app-staging app/web.1: /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.4.0/gems/railties-4.2.11.1/lib/rails/rack/logger.rb:20:in `call'
Mar 31 15:51:38 app-staging app/web.1: /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.4.0/gems/newrelic_rpm-6.3.0.355/lib/new_relic/agent/instrumentation/middleware_tracing.rb:99:in `call'
Mar 31 15:51:38 app-staging app/web.1: /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.4.0/gems/actionpack-4.2.11.1/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/request_id.rb:21:in `call'
Mar 31 15:51:38 app-staging app/web.1: /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.4.0/gems/newrelic_rpm-6.3.0.355/lib/new_relic/agent/instrumentation/middleware_tracing.rb:99:in `call'
Mar 31 15:51:38 app-staging app/web.1: /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.4.0/gems/rack-1.6.11/lib/rack/methodoverride.rb:22:in `call'
Mar 31 15:51:38 app-staging app/web.1: /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.4.0/gems/newrelic_rpm-6.3.0.355/lib/new_relic/agent/instrumentation/middleware_tracing.rb:99:in `call'
Mar 31 15:51:38 app-staging app/web.1: /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.4.0/gems/rack-1.6.11/lib/rack/runtime.rb:18:in `call'
Mar 31 15:51:38 app-staging app/web.1: /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.4.0/gems/newrelic_rpm-6.3.0.355/lib/new_relic/agent/instrumentation/middleware_tracing.rb:99:in `call'
Mar 31 15:51:38 app-staging app/web.1: /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.4.0/gems/activesupport-4.2.11.1/lib/active_support/cache/strategy/local_cache_middleware.rb:28:in `call'
Mar 31 15:51:38 app-staging app/web.1: /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.4.0/gems/newrelic_rpm-6.3.0.355/lib/new_relic/agent/instrumentation/middleware_tracing.rb:99:in `call'
Mar 31 15:51:38 app-staging app/web.1: /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.4.0/gems/actionpack-4.2.11.1/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/static.rb:120:in `call'
Mar 31 15:51:38 app-staging app/web.1: /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.4.0/gems/newrelic_rpm-6.3.0.355/lib/new_relic/agent/instrumentation/middleware_tracing.rb:99:in `call'
Mar 31 15:51:38 app-staging app/web.1: /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.4.0/gems/rack-cors-1.0.3/lib/rack/cors.rb:95:in `call'
Mar 31 15:51:38 app-staging app/web.1: /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.4.0/gems/newrelic_rpm-6.3.0.355/lib/new_relic/agent/instrumentation/middleware_tracing.rb:99:in `call'
Mar 31 15:51:38 app-staging app/web.1: /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.4.0/gems/rack-1.6.11/lib/rack/sendfile.rb:113:in `call'
Mar 31 15:51:38 app-staging app/web.1: /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.4.0/gems/newrelic_rpm-6.3.0.355/lib/new_relic/agent/instrumentation/middleware_tracing.rb:99:in `call'
Mar 31 15:51:38 app-staging app/web.1: /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.4.0/gems/railties-4.2.11.1/lib/rails/engine.rb:518:in `call'
Mar 31 15:51:38 app-staging app/web.1: /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.4.0/gems/railties-4.2.11.1/lib/rails/application.rb:165:in `call'
Mar 31 15:51:38 app-staging app/web.1: /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.4.0/gems/railties-4.2.11.1/lib/rails/railtie.rb:194:in `public_send'
Mar 31 15:51:38 app-staging app/web.1: /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.4.0/gems/railties-4.2.11.1/lib/rails/railtie.rb:194:in `method_missing'
Mar 31 15:51:38 app-staging app/web.1: /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.4.0/gems/newrelic_rpm-6.3.0.355/lib/new_relic/agent/instrumentation/middleware_tracing.rb:99:in `call'
Mar 31 15:51:38 app-staging app/web.1: /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.4.0/gems/rack-1.6.11/lib/rack/content_length.rb:15:in `call'
Mar 31 15:51:38 app-staging app/web.1: /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.4.0/gems/thin-1.7.2/lib/thin/connection.rb:86:in `block in pre_process'
Mar 31 15:51:38 app-staging app/web.1: /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.4.0/gems/thin-1.7.2/lib/thin/connection.rb:84:in `catch'
Mar 31 15:51:38 app-staging app/web.1: /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.4.0/gems/thin-1.7.2/lib/thin/connection.rb:84:in `pre_process'
Mar 31 15:51:38 app-staging app/web.1: /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.4.0/gems/thin-1.7.2/lib/thin/connection.rb:53:in `process'
Mar 31 15:51:38 app-staging app/web.1: /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.4.0/gems/thin-1.7.2/lib/thin/connection.rb:39:in `receive_data'
Mar 31 15:51:38 app-staging app/web.1: /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.4.0/gems/eventmachine-1.2.7/lib/eventmachine.rb:195:in `run_machine'
Mar 31 15:51:38 app-staging app/web.1: /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.4.0/gems/eventmachine-1.2.7/lib/eventmachine.rb:195:in `run'
Mar 31 15:51:38 app-staging app/web.1: /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.4.0/gems/thin-1.7.2/lib/thin/backends/base.rb:73:in `start'
Mar 31 15:51:38 app-staging app/web.1: /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.4.0/gems/thin-1.7.2/lib/thin/server.rb:162:in `start'
Mar 31 15:51:38 app-staging app/web.1: /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.4.0/gems/rack-1.6.11/lib/rack/handler/thin.rb:19:in `run'
Mar 31 15:51:38 app-staging app/web.1: /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.4.0/gems/rack-1.6.11/lib/rack/server.rb:287:in `start'
Mar 31 15:51:38 app-staging app/web.1: /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.4.0/gems/railties-4.2.11.1/lib/rails/commands/server.rb:80:in `start'
Mar 31 15:51:38 app-staging app/web.1: /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.4.0/gems/railties-4.2.11.1/lib/rails/commands/commands_tasks.rb:80:in `block in server'
Mar 31 15:51:38 app-staging app/web.1: /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.4.0/gems/railties-4.2.11.1/lib/rails/commands/commands_tasks.rb:75:in `tap'
Mar 31 15:51:38 app-staging app/web.1: /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.4.0/gems/railties-4.2.11.1/lib/rails/commands/commands_tasks.rb:75:in `server'
Mar 31 15:51:38 app-staging app/web.1: /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.4.0/gems/railties-4.2.11.1/lib/rails/commands/commands_tasks.rb:39:in `run_command!'
Mar 31 15:51:38 app-staging app/web.1: /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.4.0/gems/railties-4.2.11.1/lib/rails/commands.rb:17:in `<top (required)>'
Mar 31 15:51:38 app-staging app/web.1: script/rails:6:in `require'
Mar 31 15:51:38 app-staging app/web.1: script/rails:6:in `<main>'
```

FYI - This is the same code running on production and it is NOT failing.

Comment: Logs would be helpful. `heroku logs -t`

Comment: Updated with logs

Comment: Well it says, you have a request timeout. Is this a complex operation, that takes a lot of time, or does rely on some external service that may be slow?

Comment: No not complex.  The only thing I can think of is right above the log it tries AWS simple DB request.